# Is there a way to accelerate CUDA PTX JIT compilation?

Tags: c++, cuda, jit, ptx

Well, I have a program which generates, JIT-compiles and runs PTX subprograms on GPU. Programs are running just fine and the run-times are pretty good - around 500x speedup vs CPU. Problem is that the compilation takes way too long, erasing all GPU speedup turning it to slowdown :)

Question is, is there a faster, more efficient way to do this? Can I reuse some resources, make the process more stream-like?

Edit: Each PTX program is run only once, and they are all very different, so JIT caching gains no benefit

This is my code, which is pretty much the same as nvidia-provided example JIT app:

```
CHECK_ERROR(cuLinkCreate(6, linker_options, linker_option_vals, &lState));

// Load the PTX from the string myPtx32
CUresult myErr = cuLinkAddData(lState, CU_JIT_INPUT_PTX, (void*) ptxProgram.c_str(), ptxProgram.size()+1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

// Complete the linker step
CHECK_ERROR(cuLinkComplete(lState, &linker_cuOut, &linker_outSize));

// Linker walltime and info_log were requested in options above.
//printf("CUDA Link Completed in %fms. Linker Output:\n%s\n", linker_walltime, linker_info_log);

// Load resulting cuBin into module
CHECK_ERROR(cuModuleLoadData(&hModule, linker_cuOut));

// Locate the kernel entry poin
CHECK_ERROR(cuModuleGetFunction(&hKernel, hModule, "_myBigPTXKernel"));

// Destroy the linker invocation
CHECK_ERROR(cuLinkDestroy(lState));
```

Comment: I think the usual suggestion would be to compile things ahead of time, converting your ptx to cubin.  If you can't generate the ptx subprograms ahead of time, perhaps you can arrange the ptx-jit so that it takes place while other kernels are executing?  If your kernel execution time(s) is very short, that won't be very manageable either, unless you perhaps go to multithreading.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider JIT caching.
http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-pro-tip-understand-fat-binaries-jit-caching/

Comment: Thank u for suggestion. I actually don't understand why u got downvoted as JIT caching could really speed things up. Unfortunately my PTX programs are only run once, so caching is no option for me

Comment: Caching is useful if you run the program more than once

Comment: It is worth pointing out that JIT caching is automatic and the default in CUDA (and has been for years), so this answer is suggesting something that already happens and is happening in the OPs case.